# Can we invoke an exe of client machine through ChatBot application which is hosted on azure and channel to access the chatbot is MS Teams

Tags: chatbot, microsoft-teams, .net-core-3.1, botframework

I am working on a chatbot application developed in .net core 3.1, this application is hosted on azure, and all users of the company can interact with this chatbot through MS Teams app, on both platforms through mobile and desktop. So I want to do some automation on user machine, for this, I want to invoke cmd and some exes of client user machine, but I have no idea how to achieve this directly through my chatbot application. I don't want to inkove exe through the client machine browser with some registry changes on user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a massive security risk, so no, there's no way to do this without installing or implementing things on the user's machine.

Some options are:

1. Write a custom chat client using [directline-js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS), that executes those commands when it receives data from the bot.
2. [Register a custom URI Protocol handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration) and have the bot send a URL link in teams. When the user clicks it, the handler grabs it and sends it to the program registered with the handler to execute the appropriate action.

There's probably some other ways to do this but again, it's not possible without the client installing something or making some registry edits.